# Mongoose aggregate, find ancestors of product when product is matched

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Sorry for the bad title, couldn't figure a better one.

I have a parent `Product` that has an array of `ancestors` that is empty.

I also have Products that have `ancestors` that include the parent `_id` , called `variants` and Products `ancestors` that include the parent and the variant `_id` called `options`. All Products are in the same document, no refs.

**Parent Product**

```
{
 productType: 'simple'
 ancestors: [],
 title: "Test Title",
 _id: "1"
}
```

**Variant Product**

```
{
 productType: 'variant'
 ancestors: ["1"],
 title: "Test Variant",
 _id: "2"
}
```

**Option Product**

```
{
 productType: 'option'
 ancestors: ["1", "2"],
 title: "Test Variant",
 _id: "3"
}
```

When I search a product i want to include all `variants` and `options` in the search results, like:

```
products: [{
   _id: "1",
   variants: [{...}],
   options: [{...}]
 },
  ...
 ]
```

**Search endpoint**

```
 Product.aggregate([
            {$match: {productType: 'simple'}},
            {$match: {$or: [{sku: {$regex: new RegExp(makeComp(value), 'i')}}, {title: {$regex: new RegExp(makeComp(value), 'i')}}]}},
            {
                $project: {
                    _id      : 1,
                    title    : 1,
                    productType: 1,
                    ancestors: 1
                }
            },
        ], (err, result) => {
            console.log(err);
            console.log(result);
        });
```

I have tried many things after the `$project` but no luck.

Do i have to make a new `find` or `aggregate` after the product is matched or there is a way to fetch all the ancestors inside one `aggregate`?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do `find` with `$or`

```
db.products.find({$expr : {
    $or : [
        {"_id":1},
        {"productType" : "variant", "ancestors" : 1},
        {"productType" : "option", "ancestors" : 1}
    ]
}})
```

same with aggregation

```
db.products.aggregate([
    {$match: {$expr : {
        $or : [
            {"_id":1},
            {"productType" : "variant", "ancestors" : 1},
            {"productType" : "option", "ancestors" : 1}
        ]
    }}}
])
```

**EDIT-1**

with `$lookup` to get the results

```
db.products.aggregate([
    {$match: {"_id":"1"}},
    {$lookup: {
      from: "products",
      let: {id : "$_id", productType: "$productType"},
      pipeline:[{$match: {$expr: {$and: [{$in: ["$$id","$ancestors"]}, {$eq: ["$productType" ,"variant"]}]}}}],
      as: "variants"
   }},
    {$lookup: {
      from: "products",
      let: {id : "$_id", productType: "$productType"},
      pipeline:[{$match: {$expr: {$and: [{$in: ["$$id","$ancestors"]}, {$eq: ["$productType" ,"option"]}]}}}],
      as: "options"
   }}
]).pretty()
```

**EDIT-2**

with `$match`, `$group` and `$project`

```
db.products.aggregate([
    {$match: {$expr : {
        $or : [
            {"_id":1},
            {"productType" : "variant", "ancestors" : 1},
            {"productType" : "option", "ancestors" : 1}
        ]
    }}},
    {$group: {_id: "$productType", docs : {$push : "$$ROOT"}}},
    {$group: {_id: null, docs : {$push : "$docs"}}},
    {$project: {
        simple: {$arrayElemAt:[{$filter: {input : "$docs", as: "d", cond : {$in: ["simple", "$$d.productType"]}}},0]},
        variant: {$arrayElemAt:[{$filter: {input : "$docs", as: "d", cond : {$in: ["variant", "$$d.productType"]}}},0]},
        option: {$arrayElemAt:[{$filter: {input : "$docs", as: "d", cond : {$in: ["option", "$$d.productType"]}}},0]}
    }}
]).pretty()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I want to match only the ‘parent’ product when searching from front end but down the road I want to fetch any `parent` or `variant` that has `parent` `_id` inside the ancestors array.

Comment: can you please post the expected output?

Comment: If you to find grandparent, great grandparent you can do `$graphLookup`

Comment: Thanks, I’ll look at it asap, perfomance wise, is it fast enough to `$lookup`? (I have indexes in place)

Comment: I modified the first query with `$group` and `$project` to avoid two `$lookup`

Comment: Using this snippet (edit-2) will return all products that match the search criteria. I want to search only for parent, then when parent is found I want to filter all the products that have the found product's `_id` inside the `ancestors` array.